# How to store output of find from a background command

Tags: bash, find, background-process

I have the following excerpt from a script for finding certain subfolders. Meanwhile a spinner indicates that something is taking longer in the background:

```
# runs find as background task and meanwhile display spinner
# writes to temp file ./.repos
echo -ne "Scanning for .git folders ...  "
find -name ".git" -type d > .repos &
pid=$!
while [ -d /proc/$pid ]
do
    for x in '-' '/' '|' '\'
    do
        echo -ne "\b"$x
        sleep 0.01
    done
done

# read-in result from ./.repos and delete the file
echo ""
repos=$(cat .repos)
rm .repos
```

This is fine and all, **but** I don't like the writing/reading to/from a file just to get the list of found folders.

So my question is: **How could I do this directly as a variable?**

I tried something like

```
echo -ne "Scanning for .git folders ...  "
repos=$(find -name ".git" -type d &
    pid=$!
    while [ -d /proc/$pid ]
    do
        for x in '-' '/' '|' '\'
        do
            echo -ne "\b"$x
            sleep 0.01
        done
    done
)

echo "$repos"
```

but this didn't work meaning the spinner was never printed but in the end was added to the string in `$repos` itself.

So I thought I understood the issue and tried

```
echo -ne "Scanning for .git folders ...  "
repos=$(find -name ".git" -type d) &
pid=$!
while [ -d /proc/$pid ]
do
    for x in '-' '/' '|' '\'
    do
        echo -ne "\b"$x
        sleep 0.01
    done
done

echo "$repos"
```

now the spinner works as expected but in the end `$repos` is empty

Answer (score 0):

This should suit your needs:

```
echo -ne "Scanning for .git folders ...  "
(
  while :; do
      for x in '-' '/' '|' '\\'
      do
          echo -ne "\b"$x
          sleep 0.01
      done
  done
) &
sub=$!

repos=$(find -name ".git" -type d)

kill $sub
echo -ne "\nFound repos: "
echo "$repos" | wc -l
```

It's probably easier to do it the other way around.